# Weird bleeding sequence for brakes

Tags: brakes

The normal bleeding sequence is to start from the furthest wheel on to the closest wheel to the master cylinder (Right rear, left rear, right front, left front). This is pretty much the sequence on most cars I have seen. However, my car (Peugeot 405/406) is quite different. It starts with right rear but suddenly goes to left front wheel (driver side wheel)!! In most cars, driver side wheel is the shortest path to master cylinder. How is it possible that in this car, drive side wheel is the second longest brake line? Why didn't they choose the left rear as the second longest line? This is a picture from the manual showing the sequence:

[image]

I fitted a transparent hose on the bleeding nipple with the ring spanner in place. I was about to start bleeding but this weird bleeding sequence stopped me from going on.

[image: ****]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually because the brakes have split circuits, such as one rear and half the pistons on the front.

Just depends on what exactly is fitted.

If you read further or before you may find the diagram showing the split circuit detail.